track status of some specific rpc call(especially sync bi-directional streaming)
I have sync bi-directional streaming from gRPC. How to know the exact moment when connect is alive to ensure that I could send requests, or dequeue pending requests, as this stream live only 15 sec in terms of battery saving? So should I reconnect a lot? But not knowing state of this rpc it's impossible to know moment when Stream request could accept request.
Tried interceptors + sending ping requests, but they're not reliable. For example, the user changes Wi-Fi to Cellular, the IP change, but protocol doesn't emit any error, so it's impossible to track health of connect which is sync and could not be awaited.
This is bi-directional gRPC streaming
ResponseStream<Update> connect(Stream<Request> request, {CallOptions? options})

It's sync, so I need to track status of this sync connect, to know whether it's live and I can add requests to _requestStreamController.stream or I need to wait/reconnect, etc.
_channel = ClientChannel(
      baseUrl,
      port: ...,
      options: ChannelOptions(
        userAgent: userAgent,
        keepAlive: ClientKeepAliveOptions(
          pingInterval: Duration(seconds: 10),
          timeout: Duration(seconds: 3),
        ),
      ),
    );
    _customerStub = CustomerClient(
      channel,
      interceptors: [GRPCInterceptor()],
      options: CallOptionsBuilder()
          .setDeviceId(deviceId)
          .setClientToken(clientToken)
          .setAccessToken(_accessToken)
          .build(),
    );


_grpcGateway.customerStub
          .connect(_requestStreamController.stream)
          .listen(
        (update)...


Please update your question to include a minimal repro of your code that highlights the issue you're facing

@DazWilkin edited, please, check code

Thank you! Will try to take a look tomorrow

I'm not a Dart developer (familiar with gRPC) so I'll defer to your and other developers' expertise. I think (!?) Dart's gRPC library doesn't surface the low-level events (network change etc.) that you're after. I understand why this would be useful in a less predictable mobile environment. In terms of when Streams are available, I'm unsure why you're unable to try the listen((data) ...) or await for(var data in ...) and handle errors (include GrpcError).

The grpc/grpc-dart repo includes several issues pertaining to using the library in mobile scenarions e.g. proposal: FlutterClientChannel for handling mobile connection state. That may be a place to add your concerns.

@DazWilkin Okay, but this connect is stream inside channel which accept different requests and emit different responses, but there are cases when gRPC doesn’t emit any error even if connect is dead, so i need to be able to intercept this specific call and know status of it, similar like it is in Kotlin

https://github.com/dart-lang/http2/blob/master/lib/src/streams/stream_handler.dart
@DazWilkin we have info regarding stream state, but it's hidden for some reason...

Per my previous comment "Dart''s gRPC library doesn't surface low-level (e.g. HTTP/2) events". I think your question (on the GitHub repo) is more specifically: Is it possible (if so how) can a developer access the underlying HTTP/2 streams? Consider joining the gRPC Google Group (https://groups.google.com/g/grpc-io). It may be worthwhile asking for confirmation that the Dart gRPC library is in maintenance mode too.
